MFC: Why when deleting the last item of a ListBox (becomes empty) the virtual function DeleteItem() is not called?
Using MFC I sub-classed the CListBox (CBCGPListBox - for themes) to send selection change notifications when items are deleted.   This works fine for all items except the very last item deleted from the list box (list box becomes empty). In that case the DeleteItem() virtual function is NOT called.   It seems strange to me that it wouldn't be called?  Is there some other message or virtual function that deals with that?
class CMyListBox : public CBCGPListBox
{

  virtual void DeleteItem(LPDELETEITEMSTRUCT lpDeleteItemStruct)
  {
    __super::DeleteItem(lpDeleteItemStruct);
    GetParent()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(GetDlgCtrlID(), LBN_SELCHANGE), (LPARAM)m_hWnd);
  };

};


You should leave that as an answer, not a comment.  It's OK to answer your own question.  It makes sense, an owner-draw list box is responsible for handling its own data so you'd want to be notified if the configuration changes.  No idea why it would even be called for non owner draw.

The documentation states DeleteItem() is called for owner-drawn list boxes.
By changing the list box to be owner draw (which CBCGPListBox handled fine), DeleteItem() is called for all items deleted (including the final one).
